# Proper use of asp.net webforms lifecycle

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-parts

This is really a more general question, but the only way I can think to ask it is with a specific example.

We currently have a webpart with an `SPGridView`.  As it is now, the GV and all bound fields are created in `CreateChildControls`, the data is retrieved and bound in `OnPreRender`.  The columns are static so this works fine.

```
CreateChildControls{
    // create and configure the gridview
    // create all bound fields and add them to the gridview
    // add the gridview to the page
}

OnPreRender{
    // get the data and bind it to the gridview
}
```

Now we need to change the columns to be dependent on the selection made by the user from a dropdown list.  Within `CreateChildControls` we cannot get the value from the dropdown control so we can't conditionally add bound fields.  My question is, what is the best practice here?  We could create all possible bound fields in `CreateChildControls` and then only add the appropriate fields to the GV in `OnPreRender`.  We could just move the creation of all of the bound fields entirely into `OnPreRender`.  And there are really many other options.

```
CreateChildControls{
    // create and configure the gridview
    // create ALL bound fields here?
    // add the gridview to the page
}

OnPreRender{
    // or maybe create only the applicable bound fields here?
    // add the appropriate fields to the gridview
    // get the data and bind it to the gridview
}
```

And in a more general sense, what really constitutes "creating" a control (the purpose of `CreateChildControls`)?  The question really extends to any control which could have dynamic content.  Where is the appropriate place to add entries into your dropdown list, etc.  There are many ways that work, but which is "right"?  Is adding the selections into your dropdown part of "creating" the control?  Is it dependent on whether or not the selections are dynamic?

Comment: Probably not a full blown answer, but here's some _light_ reading from MSDN on the ASP.NET page life cycle.  Also note some of the comments at the bottom of the page as the provide some more info/commentary.  EDIT: helps if I include the link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Answer (score 0):

`BoundField` is not a control and the `Columns` collection in gridview is state managed so you can safely add the columns in the `PreRender` event before you databind the control.